# Edit profile picture dont safe the image path in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I want, that user can change their profile pictures, but the code dont save the image-path in the database. He is uploading the image and the connection works.

Here the code:

```
function pbchange(){
$csrf = length(isset($_POST['csrf']) ? $_POST['csrf'] : '', 32);
    $pbch = length(isset($_POST['pbchange']) ? $_POST['pbchange'] : '', 1);
$error = '';
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $target_dir = "upload/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    // Select file type
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    // Valid file extensions
    $extensions_arr = array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif");

if($pbch == 1 && $csrf == $_SESSION['csrfToken']){
                                                    // Check extension
                                                if( in_array($imageFileType,$extensions_arr) ){

                                                    // Convert to base64 
                                                    $image_base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) );
                                                    $image = 'data:image/'.$imageFileType.';base64,'.$image_base64;


                                                    $query = mysqli_query("Update na_user Set pb=".$image." Where id = '".userout('id')."'");

                                                    // Upload file
                                                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'upload/'.$name);

                                                }
                    if($query){
                        header('Location: ./?p=usersettings&h=pbchange');
                        exit;
                    } else {
                        $error = 'Fehler beim ändern des Profilbild! Bitte versuchen Sie es zu einem späteren Zeitpunkt erneut.';
                        errormail('MySQL Fehler in "Profilbild ändern", Funktion "pbchange()"');
                    }
    }
return sondertext($error);
```

}

Comment: Why are you storing the image in the database _and_ in the file system? That makes no sense, specially since you're not even storing the name of the file in the DB. You should only store it on the file system and save the name in the DB.¨

Comment: To answer your question about what's wrong, Strings need to be quoted in SQL: `pb='".$image."'`. However, you should use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Then you don't need to think about quotes or escaping. You should also check your servers error log when something doesn't work.

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks for help. ^^